# Setting opts of individual Elements in holoviews Holomaps

Tags: python, holoviews

Given a Holomap-like object (HoloMap, NdOverlay, ...) created by grouping by an additional `kdim`, is there a way to access specific sub-elements for individual styling? Given a HoloMap `p`:

```
p = hv.Dataset(([0, 1], [2, 2], ['a', 'b']), ['x', 'y', 'z']
              ).to(hv.Points, groupby='z')
```

is it possible to add individual style opts for `z='a'`, `z='b'`? I've tried the `group.label` syntax but that didn't work.

If not, I reckon I would have to create a dictionary of the Elements and pass the group label explicitly?

```
hv.HoloMap({z_value: hv.Points(..., group=z_value) for z_value in ...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could index into the HoloMap and use the `.opts` method to apply the options without cloning, e.g.:

```
p = hv.Dataset(([0, 1], [2, 2], ['a', 'b']), ['x', 'y', 'z']
          ).to(hv.Points, groupby='z')
p['a'].opts(color='red')
p['b'].opts(color='blue')
p
```